# Preview webcam in axis - disappear my x and y axis

Tags: matlab, matlab-app-designer

I want to plot a webcam in MATLAB app designer by preview in axis, but when i do it my x axis and y axis are gone.
how i can plot with showing x axis and y axis.
This is my code :

```
        app.img = webcam;
        app.frame = snapshot(app.img);
        app.im = image(app.Main_image, zeros(size(app.frame),'uint8'));
        axis(app.Main_image,'image');
        preview(app.img,app.im);
```

images:
[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYaqo.png) , [after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASK3N.png)

the preview is working, i just blocked the camera.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

i couldnt reproduce your code.
you could just add following line to your code to make axis visible :

```
ax=gca();
ax.Visible='on';
```

Comment: hey, it doesnt works for me. my axis name: app.Main_image how i can connect my axis to ax?